# checkbox.checked is not working in a listview

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I've got an aspx using master pages and .net 4.  I've using the same code on 4 different forms.  I've copied and pasted it from the other forms that are working.  Here is the code.

The listview is named lvMisc_Attachment, here is the Checkbox code

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" Checked='<%#eval("Checked") %>' />
```

and here is the code behind that is happening when someone clicks a linkbutton, the linkbutton calls teh MiscAttachment_ItemsChecked function.

```
    Private Function MiscAttachment_ItemsChecked() As String
    Dim mString As String = String.Empty
    For Each lv In Me.lvMisc_Attachment.Items
        If CType(lv.FindControl("chkChecked"), CheckBox).Checked = True Then
            If mString.Length = 0 Then
                mString = CType(lv.FindControl("hfMisc_AttachmentID"), HiddenField).Value
            Else
                mString = mString & "," & CType(lv.FindControl("hfMisc_AttachmentID"), HiddenField).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return mString
End Function
```

The checkbox does not show up as being checked when it is.  It is getting checked after the page renders.

Answer (score 0):

Add AutoPostback="true" to your checkbox in order to post contol whan he changes

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" Checked='<%#eval("Checked") %>' AutoPostback="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.. i don't want to do a postback each time a checkbox is checked.. could be multipals that are getting checked, that is why i was using a link button. I founnd my issue anyway.. i wasn't doing a if page.ispostback in the page load, so my listview was getting reloaded... thanks for the response.

Comment: I'am happy to help you jvcoach23

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I forgot to do a if page.ispost=true on the page_Load.. the listview was getting repopulated so the checkbox wasn't checked due to the reload.